# Trigger to capture specific value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `Status` in a table which changes its values. I need to capture when `Status` changes to "Stop" Or "Complete". Then I will copy entire row from table 1 to table 2. The issue that I am having is: Database is only allowing to change only one cell value, under `Status` column  instead of entire column.  How can I apply this trigger for entire column. Thank you for the response!

```
ALTER TRIGGER Name
   ON table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET nocount ON

IF EXISTS (Select * FROM table1 Where Status in('Stop','Comp')) 
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO
    Table_2 
  END
  END
```

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN`  ...  `IF OLD.Status != NEW.Status AND NEW.Status IN ('Stop','Complete')`... can you take it from there?

Comment: I tried FOR EACH ROW it is giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Having:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INTEGER, 
    column1 INTEGER, 
    STATUS CHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INTEGER, 
    column1 INTEGER, 
    STATUS CHAR(10)
);
```

If you want to insert to the new table the old values from table1 you can do something like this:

### In mySql

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER triggname AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF NEW.STATUS = 'Stop' OR NEW.STATUS = 'Comp' THEN
    INSERT INTO table2
    VALUES (old.id, old.column1, old.STATUS);
  END IF;
END
```

<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68afd/1)</kbd>

### In SQL-Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_status ON table1 AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT d.* FROM DELETED d
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON d.id = i.id 
    WHERE i.status != d.status AND i.status IN ('Comp','Stop');
END;
```

In SQL Server you have to go through the tables Inserted and Deleted which represent the NEW and OLD versions of the records updated.
<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/888fb/1)</kbd>

Comment: I have tried this. But it gives me error for For EACH ROW as syntax error in SQL management studio. Will try it again tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: @user2801184. Are you using SQL-Server? Because you tagged this as mysql.

Comment: Sorry, it is SQL server.

Comment: @user2801184. I added an sql version to the answer

Comment: I haven't used triggers much infact it's 1st time. It worked but can you please explain me what you did?

Comment: As i said, `DELETED` is a special table that contains the records before being updated and `INSERTED` contains the records after being updated. I am inserting into table2 the records that have different status before and after the update, and the new status is one of those two. To understand more about triggers you can see the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx)